# A binary combination of probability equations

Tags: probability

Let $(p_{1} ,...,p_{n})$ and $(q_{1} ,...,q_{n} )$ be two vectors of probabilities (do not sum to 1) and a scalar $0<\alpha<1$. For $n=1$ we have 2 equations,

$\alpha p_{1}=(1-\alpha) q_{1}$

$\alpha (1-p_{1})=(1-\alpha) (1-q_{1})$

It is easy to show that they can only be satisfied if $p_{1}=q_{1}$ and $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$.
I would like to know if a $generalization$ of this can be made for any $n$. For e.g., for $n=2$ we have 4 equations:

$\alpha p_{1}p_{2}=(1-\alpha) q_{1}q_{2}$

$\alpha p_{1}(1-p_{2})=(1-\alpha) q_{1}(1-q_{2})$

$\alpha (1-p_{1})p_{2}=(1-\alpha) (1-q_{1})q_{2}$

$\alpha (1-p_{1})(1-p_{2})=(1-\alpha) (1-q_{1})(1-q_{2})$

And for $n=3$ we have 8 equations, etc.

Is it true that such sets of equations can only be satisfied if for all $i:1...n$, $p_{i}=q_{i}$, and $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true.

For instance, consider the first two of your four equations in the case $n=2$:

$\alpha p_{1}p_{2}=(1-\alpha) q_{1}q_{2},$

$\alpha p_{1}(1-p_{2})=(1-\alpha) q_{1}(1-q_{2}).$

You can rewrite the second equation as:

$\alpha p_1 - \alpha p_1p_2  = (1-\alpha)q_1 - (1-\alpha)q_1q_2.$

Notice how you know from the first equation that $\alpha p_1p_2 = (1-\alpha)q_1q_2$, so these two terms cancel out from the rewritten second equation, and you end up with:

$\alpha p_1 = (1-\alpha)q_1.$

Now, if you do a similar maneuver for your third and fourth equation, you end up with the one equation:

$\alpha(1-p_1) = (1-\alpha)(1-q_1).$

These two obtained equations combined are exactly your equation for the case $n=1$, for which you know that $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$.

In general, you can do an inductive argument, taking the equations for a general $n$, and combine them pairwise to obtain the equations for the case $n-1$.

Comment: No problem, @Omri I'm glad it makes sense.